# Perform action while key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

In my program I would need that an action is perfomed *while* a key is pressed. I have already searched but the solutions either were not for c#, neither for forms or I couldnt understand them.

Is there a proper and easy solution to this?

EDIT: I am using WinForms and I want that while the form is focussed and a key is pressed an action is repeatedly performed.

Comment: Explain your scenario. Performing action on key press can mean anything from key press inside textbox to key pressed at a form level.

Comment: Are you using Winforms or Webforms?

Comment: @dotnetkid I have a form with a picturebox and a bunch of other buttons, which are not relevant for this. While the form is focussed and the user presses, for example ENTER, the box should move 1px in the right direction.

Comment: Where did you struggle? Getting the keystrokes? Throttling the events?

Comment: @Marc I dont know how to repeatedly check if a button if pressed. I just realised I could do this with a timer, but would a check for a pressed key inside the timer_tick event work?

Comment: @IanH. See answer from EpicKid. You can store the information in a field and query this field within your timer event. Simple. There are Win32 API's to query key-state but that more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to provide a bit more information and if possible some code you already tried. But nevertheless I'll try. 
The concept is relatively easy, you add a timer to your form, you add key_DOWN and key_UP events (not key pressed). You make a bool that resembles if key is currently pressed, you change its value to true on keydown and false on keyup. It will be true while you hold the key.

```
    bool keyHold = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (keyHold) 
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

    private void Key_up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Key key = (Key) sender;
        if (key == Key.A) //Specify your key here !
        {
            keyHold = false;
        }
    }

    private void Key_down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Key key = (Key)sender;
        if (key == Key.A) //Specify your key here !
        {
            keyHold = true;
        }
    }
```

**If you're trying to make a simple game on forms and you're struggling with the input delay windows has (press and hold a key, it will come up once, wait and then spam the key) This solution works for that (no pause after the initial press).

Comment: So, I tried this but nothing happens, except that the focus between my buttons and checkboxes constantly changes. How could I fix this?

Comment: Move your picture where it says : //Do stuff

Comment: @FeDe I did that but it never enters the function where it checks if the button is pressed.

Comment: @IanH.what is your timerintervall ? Pressed the key long enought ?

Comment: @FeDe the interval is set at 50ms and I set the key to Keys.A

Comment: And it doesn't trigger when you hold A ? - Try to add a MessageBox iside the timer1_tick to see id it even triggers.

Comment: @FeDe I tried and figured out that it never sets the keyHold bool to true. Apparently it never even runs checking.

Comment: Keys.Up ist the arrow up button ... You need to trigger the releasedEvent @IanH.

Comment: @FeDe I repeat, it doesnt set the keyHold bool to true even if I press the key.

Comment: @IanH. Yeah thats because the code above triggers if the arrowUp/Down keys are pressed. I have edited the answer he only needs to accept it. Meanwhile you can try to use the arrowbuttons instead of "A" and see if something happens.

Comment: @FeDe Accepted your edit, I was at work so mixed some things up haha.

Comment: @EpicKip no need to be sorry its all fine :D

Comment: @FeDe I really like this solution, but it doesnt work for me. It tells me I am missing an assembly reference for "Key".

Comment: @IanH. Moring check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx --> Add a reference to WindowsBase :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

---

In the Key down event you set the bool 'buttonIsDown' to TRUE and start the method 'DoIt' in an Separate Thread.
The code in the While loop inside the 'DoIt' method runs as long the bool 'buttonIsDown' is true and the Form is on Focus.
It stops when the Key Up event is fired or the Form loose the focus.
There you can see the 'buttonIsDown' is set to false so that the While loop stops.

---

```
      //Your Button Status
      bool buttonIsDown = false;

      //Set Button Status to down
      private void button2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Key key = sender as Key;
            if (key == Key.A)
            buttonIsDown = true;

            //Starts your code in an Separate thread.
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoIt);
        }
      //Set Button Status to up
       private void button2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Key key = sender as Key;
            if (key == Key.A)
            buttonIsDown = false;
        }

      //Method who do your code until button is up
      private void DoIt(object dummy)
      {
        While(buttonIsDown && this.Focused)
        {
            //Do your code
        }
      }
```